# Zeros of nontrivial solution of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y$ be a nontrivial solution of the BVP, $$y''+xy=0,\, x \in [a,b],\, y(a)=y(b)=0,$$ then which of the following is/are true?

1. $b>0$
2. $y$ is monotone in $(a,0)$ if $a<0<b$
3. y'(a)=0
4. y has infinitely many zeros in $[a,b]$.

Option $4$ is false, by an application of Sturm Separation theorem $y$ has finitely many zeros in $[a,b].$ Any hints for other options please?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for $x < 0$, $y$ is convex when $y > 0$ and concave when $y < 0$.

Comment: Does this tell us that $y$ is monotonically decreasing on $(a,0)$ when $y>0$?

Comment: Just the opposite.  Since $y(a) = 0$, if $y'(a) > 0$ you'll have $y'(x) \ge y'(a) > 0$ for $x \in (a,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

The Equation $$y''+xy=0$$ is Airy ODE of second order whose two linearly independent solutions as $Ai(z)$ and $Bi(z)$. We can write its solution as
$$y(x)=C Ai(z)+D Bi(z), z=\frac{2x^{3/2}}{3}$$.
Next one can determine $C,D$ by imposing the conditions that $y(a)=0=y(b)$.

You may see

https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Airy_equation

Comment: Does this answer the question ?